# file.exist for online available files in R

Tags: r

I want to test whether one file exist on gitub, file.exists() is not working:

```
t= "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jcolomb/HCS_data_1/master/Project_exampledata1/Routputs/Min_permutated_1.csv"
file.exists(t)
#FALSE
read.csv2(t) #that does work
```

I tried also:

```
 data = try(read.csv2(paste0(onlinemin,'/Min_',Name_project,'.csv'),dec = ".")
 ,T)
```

but then exists("data") is true even when try() is not successful.

any idea?

Answer (score 2):

I think `url.exists(t)` from `RCurl` library can be what you need.

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

```
require(RCurl)
url_handle<-getCurlHandle()
t= "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jcolomb/HCS_data_1/master/Project_exampledata1/Routputs/Min_permutated_1.csv"
getURL(t,header=1,nobody=1, curl = url_handle)
getCurlInfo(url_handle,"response.code")
```

404 means no good. 200 means good to go. You might be able to merge it all to one single line. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Since I did not want to use another package, I finally used

```
data = try(read.csv2(paste0(onlinemin,'/Min_',Name_project,'.csv'),dec = ".")
,T)
if (class(data)=="try-error") ...
```

not very elegant, but works.